# for loop not going over each set of lines in csv validator

Tags: awk

right guys, I have this code

```
for line in npp_test_file.csv
awk -F, '
BEGIN { FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" } 
NF!=17 { print "incorrect   amount    of fields"; exit }
!($1~/^("[A-Z0-9]{1,25}")$/) {print "1st field invalid";}
!($2~/("[[:digit:]]{1,3}")$/) {print "2nd field invalid";}
!($3~/^("[A-Z0-9]{1,8}")$/) {print "3rd field invalid";}
!($4~/^("[A-Z0-9]{0,1}")$/) {print "4th field invalid";}
!($5~/^("[A-Z0-9]{0,11}")$/) {print "5th field invalid";}
!($6~/^("")$/) {print "6th field invalid";}
!($7~/^("[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}")$/B) {print "7th field invalid";}
!($8~/^("[1-5]{1}")$/) {print "8th field invalid";}
!($9~/^("[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}")$/) {print "9th field invalid";}
!($10~/^("[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}")$/) {print "10th field invalid";}
!($11~/^("([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]")|""$/) {print "11th field invalid";}
!($12~/^("([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]")|""$/) {print "12th field invalid";}
!($13~/^("[A-Za-z0-9]{0,70}")|""$/) {print "13th field invalid";}
!($14~/^("[A-Za-z0-9]{1}")|""$/) {print "14th field invalid";}
!($15~/^("[0-9]{0,3}")$/) {print "15th field invalid";}
!($16~/^(".+")$/) {print "16th field invalid";}
!($17~/^(".+")|""$/) {print "17th field invalid";}
{print "you have 17 fields";
exit}' $line
done
```

now this code is meant to take the data held within npp_test_file.csv and then split it into 17 fields and then assign each of those fields to a variable so that It can then test each field meets a set of given criteria.

however due to the files having more than one set of 17 fields they could have upwards of a 100 or so in one file. I need a way for the program to loop back for each line I though my code `for line` would work but it hasn't.

example of data in csv file

```
"AAA0002","112","BA001000","","HG55USW","","2018-06-21","1","2018-06-21","2018-06-21","11:26:30","11:26:30","colchester","2","003","some form of string",""
"ABC0004","a009","BAV01000","A","HG43FHG","","2018-06-21","1","2018-06-21","2018-06-21","11:26:30","11:26:30","bridgend","1","112","a second form of string ",""
"aADF0005","s012","BA0Q1000","1","CV63LTG","","2018-06-21","1","2018-06-21","2018-06-21","11:26:30","11:26:30","london","1","112","another form of string","none"
```

this should print to the screen "field one is invalid and field two is invalid"

Comment: Post some sample data with working and problematic lines with the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: added example data to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following(since samples are NOT present so didn't test it).

```
awk '
BEGIN { FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" } 
NF!=17 { print "incorrect   amount    of fields"; next}
!($1~/^("[A-Z0-9]{1,25}")$/) {print "1st field invalid";}
!($2~/("[[:digit:]]{1,3}")$/) {print "2nd field invalid";}
!($3~/^("[A-Z0-9]{1,8}")$/) {print "3rd field invalid";}
!($4~/^("[A-Z0-9]{0,1}")$/) {print "4th field invalid";}
!($5~/^("[A-Z0-9]{0,11}")$/) {print "5th field invalid";}
!($6~/^("")$/) {print "6th field invalid";}
!($7~/^("[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}")$/B) {print "7th field invalid";}
!($8~/^("[1-5]{1}")$/) {print "8th field invalid";}
!($9~/^("[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}")$/) {print "9th field invalid";}
!($10~/^("[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}")$/) {print "10th field invalid";}
!($11~/^("([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]")|""$/) {print "11th field invalid";}
!($12~/^("([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]")|""$/) {print "12th field invalid";}
!($13~/^("[A-Za-z0-9]{0,70}")|""$/) {print "13th field invalid";}
!($14~/^("[A-Za-z0-9]{1}")|""$/) {print "14th field invalid";}
!($15~/^("[0-9]{0,3}")$/) {print "15th field invalid";}
!($16~/^(".+")$/) {print "16th field invalid";}
!($17~/^(".+")|""$/) {print "17th field invalid";}
{print "you have 17 fields"}' npp_test_file.csv
```

Following are the corrections made in OP's attempt:

1- Removed `for` loop since `awk` could read Input_file itself and moreover OP looks like reading only 1 Input_file.

2- Removed `exit` from condition of `NF` checking else it will NOT check all conditions.

3- Removed `-F` from your code when you are giving `FPAT` then no need of it IMHO.

4- Removed 2nd `exit` from `print` command when 17 fields are found too.

---

---

***EDIT:*** In case you want to move to next line when any field is Invalid(even a single field) then you could add `next` to conditions for example.

```
awk '
BEGIN { FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" } 
NF!=17 { print "incorrect   amount    of fields"; next}
!($1~/^("[A-Z0-9]{1,25}")$/) {print "1st field invalid"; next}
!($2~/("[[:digit:]]{1,3}")$/) {print "2nd field invalid"; next}
!($3~/^("[A-Z0-9]{1,8}")$/) {print "3rd field invalid"; next}
!($4~/^("[A-Z0-9]{0,1}")$/) {print "4th field invalid"; next}
!($5~/^("[A-Z0-9]{0,11}")$/) {print "5th field invalid"; next}
!($6~/^("")$/) {print "6th field invalid"; next}
!($7~/^("[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}")$/B) {print "7th field invalid"; next}
!($8~/^("[1-5]{1}")$/) {print "8th field invalid"; next}
!($9~/^("[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}")$/) {print "9th field invalid"; next}
!($10~/^("[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}")$/) {print "10th field invalid"; next}
!($11~/^("([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]")|""$/) {print "11th field invalid"; next}
!($12~/^("([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]")|""$/) {print "12th field invalid"; next}
!($13~/^("[A-Za-z0-9]{0,70}")|""$/) {print "13th field invalid"; next}
!($14~/^("[A-Za-z0-9]{1}")|""$/) {print "14th field invalid"; next}
!($15~/^("[0-9]{0,3}")$/) {print "15th field invalid"; next}
!($16~/^(".+")$/) {print "16th field invalid"; next}
!($17~/^(".+")|""$/) {print "17th field invalid"; next}
{print "you have 17 fields"}' npp_test_file.csv
```

---

---

***EDIT2:*** Taking inspiration from @NeronLeVelu's solution here. Modifying his solution to make automatic array from REGEX(which will be used for different field's checking). Though I have not tested it since no proper samples as mentioned before too.

```
awk '
   BEGIN{
      FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
      Fld = 0
      num=split("^(\"[A-Z0-9]{1,25}\")$,(\"[[:digit:]]{1,3}\")$,^(\"[A-Z0-9]{1,8}\")$,^(\"[A-Z0-9]{0,1}\")$,^(\"[A-Z0-9]{0,11}\")$,^(\"\")$,^(\"[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}\")$,^(\"[1-5]{1}\")$,^(\"[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}\")$,^(\"[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}\")$,^(\"([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\")|\"\"$,^(\"([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\")|\"\"$,^(\"[A-Za-z0-9]{0,70}\")|\"\"$,^(\"[A-Za-z0-9]{1}\")|\"\"$,^(\"[0-9]{0,3}\")$,^(\".+\")$,^(\".+\")|\"\"$", array",")
      for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
         regex[i]=array[i]
      }

    NF != 17 { 
       printf( "Line %3d : incorrect amount of fields\n", NR )
       next
       }

    {
    for (Idx=1; Idx<=num; Idx++ ) {
       if ( $Idx !~ regex[Idx] ) {
          printf( "Line %3d : %2dth field is invalid\n", NR, Idx )
          }
       }
    }'  Input_file
```

Comment: you can use the variable num (recall it maybe NbFld) in your test `NF != num`, there is a `,` missing in the split just after array (near end of line ). Suggestion, split the string in the split line to have 1 regex per line (using `\`) to be more easy to adapt and read (this is why i use direct array assignation in this case)

Answer (score 2):

a more generic version where you put all your pattern check in a array 'easier to adapt with other count of field, i use Fld var auto incremented but you can put direct index if you prefer):

```
awk -F ',' '
   BEGIN{
      FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
      Fld = 0

      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"[A-Z0-9]{1,25}\")$"
      Pat[++Fld]="(\"[[:digit:]]{1,3}\")$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"[A-Z0-9]{1,8}\")$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"[A-Z0-9]{0,1}\")$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"[A-Z0-9]{0,11}\")$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"\")$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}\")$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"[1-5]{1}\")$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}\")$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"[0-9]{4}[-/][0-9]{2}[-/][0-9]{2}\")$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\")|\"\"$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\")|\"\"$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"[A-Za-z0-9]{0,70}\")|\"\"$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"[A-Za-z0-9]{1}\")|\"\"$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\"[0-9]{0,3}\")$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\".+\")$"
      Pat[++Fld]="^(\".+\")|\"\"$"
      }

    NF != 17 { 
       printf( "Line %3d : incorrect amount of fields\n", NR )
       next
       }

    {
    for (Idx=1; Idx<=Fld; Idx++ ) {
       if ( $Idx !~ Pat[Idx] ) {
          printf( "Line %3d : %2dth field is invalid\n", NR, Idx )
          }
       }
    }

    { printf( "Line %3d : you have 17 fields\n", NR ) }
    ' npp_test_file.csv
```

Comment: @NeronLeVelu, thank you for sharing nice solution. I have tried a bit more generic version of yours, could you please check it once in my post and let me know your views. Will be grateful to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove that `exit` from the last block (and while you're at it, remove that `-F,`, you don't need that and `FPAT`):

```
...
{print "you have 17 fields";
exit}
```

becomes

```
...
{
    print "you have 17 fields"
}
```

output will be

```
you have 17 fields
2nd field invalid
you have 17 fields
1st field invalid
2nd field invalid
you have 17 fields
```

Is this what you were looking for with *field one is invalid and field two is invalid"*?